# How to calculate Average by using case statement in Tableau Calculated Field?

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I have data in the below structure:

```
Label Person Id  Department   Team
Entry   1        Software     Testing
Entry   2        Software     Testing
Entry   3        Software     Developing
Entry   4        Software     Developing
Entry   5        Software     Developing
In      1        Software     Testing
In      3        Software     Developing
Out     2        Software     Developing
Out     4        Software     Testing
Out     5        Software     Testing
```

I require the below kind of output, but without changing the data structure in table:

```
Department  Entry  In(%)   Out(%)
Software     5      40       60
```

Comment: What exactly are you requesting?

Comment: In a Single Row , i need to show the count for One column and Percentage for other two columns

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Tableau version to try but you could achieve your target with something like

Number of `Entry` rows

```
SUM(IF [Label]="Entry" THEN 1 END)
```

Percentage of `In` rows

```
IF SUM(IF [Label]="Out" THEN 1 ELSEIF [Label]="In" THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)<>0
THEN SUM(IF [Label]="In" THEN 1 END)/SUM(IF [Label]="Out" THEN 1 ELSEIF [Label]="In" THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
ELSE NULL END
```

Percentage of `Out` rows

```
IF SUM(IF [Label]="Out" THEN 1 ELSEIF [Label]="In" THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)<>0
THEN SUM(IF [Label]="Out" THEN 1 END)/SUM(IF [Label]="Out" THEN 1 ELSEIF [Label]="In" THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
ELSE NULL END
```